# changing comma to period using conditional formatting (excel2016)

Tags: excel, formatting

I'm running into an issue.
I have created a excel sheet to aid in logging hours.

But excel uses a comma as a decimal separator, But the oracle system where it is pasted in uses a comma as thousands separator and a period as decimal separator.

The sheet needs to be idiot proof and has a set lay-out so oracle recognizes it properly.

So working with formula's isn't a real option.
Also changing de decimal separator in excel from comma to period will lead to problems in other applications.

This leaves me with conditional formatting (as far as I know)

I'm not familiar with macro's unfortunately, but it's never to late to learn.

For the sake of getting your help the protection in the first sheet is turned off:

[Link to File](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/a1a4f0bd5abc9cc2315314ba570f215520210330085829/9fe973)

Hope you guys can help me out.

**How it is**
[image: hoe it is]

**what it needs to become**
[image: what it needs to become]

Comment: can you please use screenshots to demonstrate your question and desired outcome?

Comment: added them in the OP

Comment: I'm surprised your Oracle system doesn't have a switch to set the thousand/decimal separators for incoming file. How are sending the information from Excel to Oracle?

Comment: just plain simple copy-paste.
Found the option to change the decimal indicator from period to comma.

Comment: just plain simple copy-paste.
Found the option to change the decimal indicator from period to comma.
Thank you very much, this made my day :)
pity the IT department couldn't come up with that one....